# Community Promotion Ads - 2016

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's 2048 eventually, but it's 2016 now, and we've [made some changes to the sidebar size](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites). As such, we can now restart the Community Promotion Ads for 2016!

Keep in mind, we have updated some of the guidelines compared to previously - the changes are marked in bold in the Image Requirements section.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- your ventrilo or Mumble server
- the site's twitter account
- resources or databases for gaming information
- indie games that are awesome, but people might not know about
- game servers or gaming nights
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **300 x 250 pixels**, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of **150 KB**
- **If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.**

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/11204).

Comment: The click stat page is still using the old aspect ratio, so the ads look squashed. It's also reporting zero clicks for everything

Comment: I see that there is an imgur requirement. Does this mean that we can't do dynamic ads anymore? I was planning to show donation count on Mario Marathon ad I'm planning.

Answer (score 31):

[image: Give games to kids in hospital]

Answer (score 23):

[image: Humble Bundle]

Answer (score 17):

[image: Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange]

Comment: Isn't the GameCube line a little misleading?

Comment: @AssortedTrailmix Nope. Dolphin (Wii and GameCube emulator) works on Linux.

Comment: @Ev1l0rd But Trailmix is right, the Pi is too slow to run it, my mistake - I think I just googled a bunch of gaming-related projects - that one was probably an explanation of why you can't. N64 games do run on the latest Pi3 though, so when I'm at my Ps machine I'll update it.

Comment: Working on making the EverQuest for Mac emulator server code to compile and run on it. Making great steps.

Answer (score 15):

[image: OpenTTD - Transport Tycoon for the 21st century]

Answer (score 11):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted, now with 80px more width! It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Comment: Here's a version with *another* 300px of width. Still weighs in at only 10kb! http://i.stack.imgur.com/nYKpz.png

Answer (score 10):

[image: Game Development Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Movies & TV Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 5):

[image: An advert for Retrocomputing Stack Exchange, featuring Pac-man, Space Invaders and Tetris. Remember these? Come to Retrocomputing Stack Exchange and share your knowledge!]

Comment: For more information about this ad, please see this [Retrocomputing Meta post](//meta.retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/335/278).

Answer (score 3):

[image: Lifehacks Stack Exchange]

Comment: -1 Not a bagel related question

Comment: @Wipqozn Make your own ad!

Comment: Easier to just complain about yours

Comment: I love how this has more than 15 upvotes.

Comment: *\*Advertising his own Q&A\** :-)

Answer (score -7):

[image: Q&A for ROBLOX gamers, developers and enthusiasts]

Comment: Roblox has their own forums. Not really needed here. Also we have a [roblox] tag already for people that ask questions on it.