# AskDifferent community ad shown on Arqade

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertisements

I was viewing [a question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/259057/1-9-custom-spawn-egg-riding-area-cloud) today, and to my surprise, this ad popped up:

[image]

Yup. An [ad submitted on **AskDifferent's** meta](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2719) which shows the active bounties on **AskDifferent** was served on **Arqade**.

Note that [there isn't a similar community ad currently submitted for Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11204/community-promotion-ads-2016), so it can't of been a mix-up between the sites.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce, due to the very low chance of a community ad showing (lots of hot network q's and other things)

Comment: I just seen this. Why is this considered a bug?

Comment: Can confirm, it happened to me too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm responsible for this. Per my post [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/276681/178809), I am trying to fix what is wrong with delivery of community ads. Clearly, I zigged when I should've zagged. :-) I'm working on a solution now.

---

Looks to be resolved now! Thanks for reporting this!